# Get message in Vue Js client WebSocket

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, websocket, django-channels

**On the server side:**
I have Celery function which runs periodically and produces notifications. Notifications are sent from celery to a Django-Channel consumer and pushed in a channel.

**On the client side:**
My client is a Vue Js app which communicates with the backend through WebSockets and gets notifications.

**Problem:**
The handshake connection between client and server works fine. The problem is that the client needs to make a request first to get the notification, although the notification message is already pushed in the channel by the backend. How can vuejs just listen to incoming notifications, without the need to send a request in order to get the message in the socket?

**VueJs client (Websockets)**

```
import Vue from "vue"

const socket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org")

const emitter = new Vue({
  methods:{
    send(message){
      if (1 === socket.readyState)
        socket.send(message)
    }
  }
})

socket.onmessage = function(msg){
  emitter.$emit("message", msg.data)
}
socket.onerror = function(err){
  emitter.$emit("error", err)
}


export default emitter
```

```
  import Socket from "./socket"
    
    export default {
    name: 'app',
        data(){
            return {
                messages: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
     handleMessage(msg){
             this.messages.push(msg) 
         }
        },
        created(){
            Socket.$on("message", this.handleMessage)
        },
        beforeDestroy(){
            Socket.$off("message", this.handleMessage)
        }
  }
```

**Celery task (python backend)**

```
@celery_app.task()
def notify():
    text_data = {"message": "This is a notification!"}   
    text_data = json.dumps(text_data)
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("group_1", {"type": "chat.message",
                                                         "message": text_data})
```

**Django channels consumer**

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            "group_1",
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()


    async def receive(self, text_data):

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            "group_1",
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("group_1", self.channel_name)


    async def message(self, event):
        await self.send(event['message'])
        print(f"Got message {event['message']} in group {self.group_name}")
```

Comment: You don't have a handler which corresponds to the `chat.message` type. What you have is a `message` handler. So either rename it to `chat_message` or change the name of the handler you are calling from your celery task and receive method to `message`